# Use NodeJS to run YUI compressor for output file

Tags: node.js

I tried to use YUI Compressor to compress my js file through NodeJS according to the [document](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor#nodejs-package).
I `require` the module, successfully output the compressed string. Then I tried to  output any file, but failed. The document says the option `-o` is used for output file.

Is it possible to use `-o` in NodeJS as well ? How ?

P.S., I know [how to output file in java command](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/) (YUI Compressor is based on java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope you can't pass `-o` in the options sent from your node program ([these](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/blob/80de90c82ad9a5f07aa84bf0c3091633c8ba1fcf/nodejs/index.js#L23-L30) are the valid options if you use the compressor in a node program) however you can write the file on your own

```
var compressor = require('yuicompressor');
var fs = require('fs');

compressor.compress('/path/to/file or String of JS', {
    //Compressor Options:
    charset: 'utf8',
    type: 'js',
    nomunge: true,
    'line-break': 80
}, function(err, data, extra) {
    //err   If compressor encounters an error, it's stderr will be here
    //data  The compressed string, you write it out where you want it
    //extra The stderr (warnings are printed here in case you want to echo them
    if (err) throw err
    fs.writeFileSync('./output.js', data)
});
```